# How can I set custom field date field for default date to be today's date?

Tags: dates

The threads I have seen are from 2009...

Is there a solution for this in 2018?

Something that would dynamically set current date as default?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is possible through UI configuration. The form only allows you to enter valid date but not now(), CURRENT_DATE() etc. However it is definitely possible by adding a small code in a extension.

1. Create and enable a new CiviCRM extension
2. Implement the hook_civicrm_buildForm in your extension

For the appropriate variable do:

```
function ext_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'REPLACE_WITH_FORMNAME') {
    $defaultDate = [];
    CRM_Utils_Date::getAllDefaultValues($defaultDate);
    $defaults['custom_XXX'] = $defaultDate;
    $form->setDefaults($defaults);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in what file do I input this code? What exact path?

Comment: You will need to create a extension using Civix and then implement the hook.

Comment: That sounds a little complicated...when I create a contact, on the bottom of the form is says: "Last Change by: Bruno Vincent (September 11th, 2018 4:43 PM)  » " , now what I would like is a filed that shows up in views displaying a datecreated field, how could I do that?

Comment: I am getting error on civi 5.65, is this still functional ? @PradeepNayak-CircleInt.

Comment: Nope, that's just the snippet